# Error BC30456 in single page ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've just started working through a ASP.NET C# guide to assist me with an internship I'm starting next week.  I'm familiar with OO, but never used C# or ASP.NET.  In the beginning of this tutorial, I've created a simple webpage that is supposed to analyze the interest from an IRA account.  There are two buttons, which are tagged with event handlers that refer to the C# code-behind file.  I'm receiving the following errors from the browser, after compiling and running the program:

C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite2\Default.aspx(49) : error BC30456: 'btnCalculate_click' is not a member of 'ASP.default_aspx'.

```
        AddHandler __ctrl.Click, AddressOf Me.btnCalculate_click
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite2\Default.aspx(52) : error BC30456: 'btnClear_Click' is not a member of 'ASP.default_aspx'.

```
        AddHandler __ctrl.Click, AddressOf Me.btnClear_Click
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is my .aspx file:

```
    <xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title>Chapter 2: Future Value</title>
<style type ="text/css">
.style1 
{
    color: #0000FF;
    font-size: x-large;
}
.style2 
{
    width:100%;
}
.style3 
{
    width: 140px;
    height: 23px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<span class="style1"><strong>401K Future Value</strong></span> <br /> <br />
<table class = "style2">
    <tr>
            <td class="style3">Montly investment</td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonthlyInvestment" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="style3">Annual interest rate</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtInterestRate" runat="server" Width="100px">6.0</asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="style3">Number of years</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtYears" runat="server" Width="100px">10</asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="style3">Future Value</td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblFutureValue" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td class="style3">
            <asp:Button ID="Calculate" runat="server" onclick="btnCalculate_click" Text="Calculate" />
            </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Clear" runat="server" onclick="btnClear_Click" Text="Clear" />
            </td>                        
        </tr>
</table>


</div></form>
</body>  
</html>
```

And here is my code-behind file:

```
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        for (int i = 50; i <= 500; i += 50)
            ddlMonthlyInvestment.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}

protected void btnCaluculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        int monthlyInvestment = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonthlyInvestment.SelectedValue);
        decimal yearlyInterestRate = Convert.ToDecimal(txtInterestRate.Text);
        int years = Convert.ToInt32(txtYears.Text);

        int months = years * 12;
        decimal monthlyInterestRate = yearlyInterestRate / 12 / 100;

        decimal futureValue = this.CalculateFutureValue(monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);

        lblFutureValue.Text = futureValue.ToString("c");

    }
}

protected decimal CalculateFutureValue(int monthlyInvestment, decimal monthlyInterestRate, int months)
{
    decimal futureValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < months; i++)
    {
        futureValue = (futureValue + monthlyInvestment) * (1 + monthlyInterestRate);
    }
    return futureValue;
}

protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlMonthlyInvestment.SelectedIndex = 0;
    txtInterestRate.Text = "";
    txtYears.Text = "";
    lblFutureValue.Text = "";
}
```

}

Could someone please let me know why these errors are popping up?  I've retyped both of these from the source.  Could there be a setting that I might need to have changed?  I've never used VS2010, so I'm not 100% familiar with it, either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is VB.NET. It's the VB way to add an event handler, C# uses the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ASPX file I do not see your `@Page` and `CodeFile` declarations.

Based on your question it would look something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Also, you should might want to read up on partial classes since this is how the code-behind model works:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Also you have

```
onclick="btnCalculate_click"
```

but

```
protected void btnCaluculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Spelling is different.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by doing a Copy/Paste of an aspx page or ascx user control and not cleaning up the class name (vb file) and references (aspx file) of either the original or the copy.

If you have published 'messed up' files, you can try recopying the BIN folder. 
This happened to me and something was cached somewhere. I tried stopping and starting IIS , all the pools. 
finally a reboot fixed it.

There is a locked thread here that gives a lot of good things to look at.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1000979.aspx?BC30456+Theme+is+not+a+member+of+ASP+default_aspx+