# Page Event 'onClick' causes error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, onclick

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConnect" runat="server" Text="Connect" OnClick="btnConnect_Click"/>

Protected Sub btnConnect_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
    con.Open()
    MsgBox("Hi..")
End Sub
```

The above code shows an error whilst running the page.

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>   Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'btnConnect_Click' is not a member of 'ASP.register_page_aspx' <asp:Button ID="btnConnect" runat="server" Text="Connect" OnClick="btnConnect_Click"/>

How can this issue be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you develop using WebForms, this could be the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10390940/2093029

Essentially, in your ASPX file you need to ensure that page and codefile properties are correctly declared.

Please post the full code behind and aspx page.

Here is an example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```